# How to dynamically load scripts from AWS bucket in your component(once the Dom finds the div related to scripts) in angular 11?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dynamic, angular11

I have loaded the script through this method:

```
let node = document.createElement('script');
node.src = url;
node.type = 'text/javascript';
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

Thus script has been loaded(checked with consoling through onload function) but the div related to this script is not showing any content in the inspect elements bar in browser.